# Is there a way to access Dialog objects from MainActivity?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to access the object of Dialog in MainActivity.
For example, in the MainActivity, use the Button to pop up a dialog.

```
case R.id.txtCalibMain:
    SubMenu_Calib mCalibDialog = new SubMenu_Calib(instance);
    mCalibDialog.show();
    break;
```

In this way, but in the previous steps, before the Dialog
If you want to preserve the text content of the TextView inside the Dialog
How can you approach it?

Currently, Dialog is defined and called by using a separate class.
I'm trying to access it from the outside, so I'm importing a null value or an undefined TextView.
It is natural that an error will be raised.

Dialog Activity Code

```
public class SubMenu_Units extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static SubMenu_Units mSubMenu_Units;
    public static MainActivity instance;
    public static List<SingleItem> singleItems;
    static SingleAdapter mSingleAdapter;
    public static TextView mtxtTestMenu;

    public SubMenu_Units(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.submenu_units_layout);

        mSubMenu_Units = this;

        initialize();
        mtxtTestMenu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTestCenterMenu);
    }

    void initialize()
    {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        ColorDrawable dialogColor = new ColorDrawable(0xFF424957); // 0xFF424957
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dialogColor);

        mOrientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

            WindowManager.LayoutParams mPortrait_params = getWindow().getAttributes();
            mPortrait_params.width = 375;
            mPortrait_params.height = 945;
            mPortrait_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT;
            mPortrait_params.x = 5;
            mPortrait_params.y = 68;
            getWindow().setAttributes(mPortrait_params);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to add text to Dialog's textview before the dialog is showing? It doesn't make sense though. It's like you want to set text in Activity before activity starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have common class where you need to copy below code

i.e; You need to extend below CurrentActivity with CommonActivity

//In Current Activity

```
  case R.id.txtCalibMain:
       exitAlert("Some Message)
        break;
```

// Main Acitivty

```
public void exitAlert(final String message) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View mExitAlertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_exit_logout_dialog, null);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(mExitAlertView);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            TextView txtAlertMessage = (TextView) mExitAlertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertMessage);
            txtAlertMessage.setText(message);

            mExitAlertView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            });

            Button btnExitAlertNo = (Button) mExitAlertView.findViewById(R.id.btnExitAlertNo);
            btnExitAlertNo.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.dismiss());

            Button btnExitAlertYes = (Button) mExitAlertView.findViewById(R.id.btnExitAlertYes);
            btnExitAlertYes.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: Should this code be inside DialogActivity? Or should it exist in MainActivity?

Comment: @Yuha it shoud be in MainActivity

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand.
Is this to change the TextView inside Dialog before accessing DialogActivity from MainActivity and creating Dialog?

Comment: I added the code, which seemed a bit lacking in explanation. The current Dialog is defined as a separate class, which is defined internally in such a way. I want to put some value in advance in the TextView inside Dialog before launching that Dialog. Of course, in this case, of course, FindViewByid is undefined and has a null value error, so I want to know how to fix this.

Comment: You need any explanation please let me know!

Comment: I solved this problem. Thanks,
But how do you access the Fragment as a similar type and change the Text of the Button?

Comment: You need to type cast i.e; ((Main activity.class)getActivity()).dialogName(); instead of getActivity () you can pass Context if needed